# Передача разных массивов в функцию

Tags: c++

Один двумерный массив определён статически, второй динамически. Как передать их в одну и ту же функцию через указатель? (без перегрузки)

*Почему* статический нельзя передать так же, как и динамический? Ведь это одно и тоже (указатель на указатели).

```
const int n = 5; // строки
const int m = 10; // столбцы

void print_bad(int mas[n][m])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void print_good(int **mas)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

.....

int one[n][m];
int **two;

.....

print_good(one); // не работает, а хотелось бы!
print_bad(one); // работает, но не нравится
print_good(two); // работает
```

Comment: Я бы это сделал через шаблоны.

Comment: Тип int** и int (*)[10] -  это совсем не одно и то же.

Comment: @artyomdevyatov, а Вы внимательно посмотрите, как делаете динамический массив (какой идиот назвал так массив указателей на массивы? (а вот, прижилось)) и подумайте, как данные в памяти лежат.

Вопрос отпадет.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что в случае со статическим массивом память распределятся так: ссылка на строку (она же ссылка на первый элемент), ссылки на все элементы этой строки, затем ссылка на следующую строку и так далее. А в случае с динамическим массивом: сначала ссылки на все строки, потом ссылки на все элементы. Верно?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[[@artyomdevyatov](/users/7005/artyomdevyatov)](/users/7005/artyomdevyatov), если Вы строите "динамический массив" так

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cat dyna.cpp
#include <iostream>

const int n = 5, m = 10;

void f (int **a)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
      std::cout << a[i][j] <<  ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}

int main ()
{
  int **two = new int *[n];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    two[i] = new int [m];
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
      two[i][j] = i*m + j;
  }
  f(two);
}
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ dyna.cpp 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

то данные в памяти лежат (условно) следующим образом в [] "адрес", после ':' значение

```
two = [1000]:10000
[10000]:20000 [10004]:20100 [10008]:20200 [10012]:20300 [10016]:20400
   это блок памяти, на который ссылается указатель two и он содержит адреса первых
   элементов 5-ти строк "массива"
[20000]:0 [20004]:1 .... [20036]:9  это первая строка
[20100]:10 ...           [20136]:19
....
[20400]:40 ...           [20436]:49 числа последней строки
```

Как видите они лежат **не подряд**.

А вот так будет расположен в памяти двумерный массив

```
one[n][m]

[10000]:0  ... [10036]:9    первая строка
[10040]:10 ... [10076]:19   вторая строка
   ....
[10160]:40 ... [10196]:49   пятая строка (надеюсь с подсчетом адресов не напутал)
```

Думаю, теперь понятно, почему одной и той же функцией нельзя обрабатывать 'one`и 'two`.

На мой вкус проблема проще всего решается созданием "двумерного динамического" массива в том же формате, что и традиционного. Т.е. Вы пишете

```
  int *dyna2 = new int[n * m];
  int nn = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
      dyna2[i*m + j] = nn++;

  f2 (dyna2, n, m);
  f2 (&one[0][0], n, m);
```

а в функции работаете одинаково

```
void f2 (int *a, int rows, int columns)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
      std::cout << a[i*columns + j] <<  ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

К отличному ответу [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) добавлю лишь, что если вы работаете с языком C++, рекомендуется [отказаться](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html) насколько возможно от нативных массивов, и использовать контейнеры. Тогда вопросы о размещении элементов в памяти, типичные для C, отпадут сами собой:

```
void print_cpp(const vector< vector<int> >int& mas)
{
    for (auto const& row : mas)
    {
        for (auto const& val : row)
            cout << val << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Только нужно помнить, что данные хранимые в **vector**, при добавлении новых элементов могут "переехать" в другое место. 

Поэтому пользоваться указателями на них нельзя.

Comment: @avp: ... и итераторами, тоже.

Comment: @VladD, и в C++ тоже? 

--

Я как-то налетел на некорректное поведение итераторов в Java (не помню точно, кажется в ArrayList) при изменении коллекции. Причем (по крайней мере "на виду") в документации и учебниках об этом ни слова (поэтому был уверен, что уж в разрекламированной Java все сделано корректно).

Интересно, зачем вообще делать такой ненадежный (а плане "ошибкоустойчивости") механизм?

--

Когда-то я задумывал такую штуку к одной хэш-таблице на Си, но из-за крайней неэффективности реализации отказался от этой затеи. Проще открыть все потроха структуры данных.

(опять места мало!)

Comment: @avp: да, по ссылке в предыдущем комментарии есть точные номера разделов стандарта, которые это описывают. Собственно, итератор -- не что иное, как скрытый указатель :)

Comment: @VladD, забавно про vector написано

    Insertion:  all iterators and references before the point of insertion are unaffected
    Erasure:     every iterator and reference after the point of erase is invalidated

суть та же - все итераторы после точки вставки/удаления становятся недействительными, но зачем так по разному писать?

Вот и все в крестах так.

Comment: @avp: тут есть тонкость: для insertion итераторы после вставки в принципе имеют право остаться действительными, а при удалении гарантированно недействительны. Хотя для программиста эта тонкость ничего не значит и ничего не даёт.

Comment: @avp: в плане надёжности мне нравится механизм .NET: они вообще отказались от итераторов, а операции с подмассивами делаются в технике LINQ через функциональные Where/Skip/Take/Select.

Comment: @VladD, IMHO при единичной вставке итератор "after" будет указывать на уже выданный им же ранее элемент.

Про технику же LINQ ничего сказать не могу, просто не знаком с ней.